Improved site description
I've noticed the site description for Bitcoin SE, shown in the sites overview and in search engines, has not changed since its inception in 2011:

Q&A for Bitcoin crypto-currency enthusiasts

Now, I don't know how exactly this description came to be back in the day, but I feel like it could use some improvement. How about "Q&A for Bitcoin users, developers and enthusiasts"? It specifies the scope in more detail and gets rid of the somewhat controversial term "cryptocurrency" (with a hyphen, no less). I'd be interested to know if you like it, have another proposal or think the current description doesn't need changing.

I asked the community team how one might update that description.

I was told that this description is set on Stack Exchange’s side somewhere, but if this proposal gets more support, we can get it done.

This meta post describes the process: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393320/whats-the-process-of-changing-site-description

Wish granted. The site description has been updated.

I agree that the site description should be improved. I like Vojtěch’s suggestion:

Q&A for Bitcoin users, developers and enthusiasts


Agreed! I like Vojtěch’s suggestion too

I agree with this description change as well.

Agreed. The change would more accurately reflects the site's updated scope as well.

I feel like we've reached consensus on this
